# Cross-domain request in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-domain, opensocial

I am developing an OpenSocial gadget (JavaScript language) for RQM (Rational Quality Manager) that gets information from DWA (Doors Web Access). The gadget is running on RQM (https://:9443/) and I want to make request to the DWA (https://:8443/).

The gadget runs correctly in IE, but when I run in Firefox I get the following error:

```
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://<host>:8443/xxxx. (Reason: CORS header
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown> Cross-Origin Request
> Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
> at https://<host>:8443/xxxx. (Reason: CORS request failed). <unknown>
```

What could be the issue and what can I do? Is there anything I can do on the client side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a cross origin request problem - read about CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

CORS stands for Cross Domain Resource Sharing. Because of the same origin policy you are not allowed to make requests to other URI schemes, port number, hostname etc (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You are trying to make a request to another portnumber. Solutions to this are CORS, JSONP and web sockets. But the best thing you could do is use CORS. For more information you on how to implement is you can look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I've already tried to use CORS but as far as i'm concerned it requires that the server has to be CORS-compatible. Am I worng?

Comment: Indeed. You could try to contact server-side and ask to enable CORS or you could try JSONP.

Comment: When you say 'or you could try JSONP', do you mean that this method does not require changes on the server side, only on the client side?

Comment: The server needs to be JSONP enabled...(Don't know if that is the case here) The idea behind JSONP is that by using a script tag the domain limitation will ignored. Just thought about something else. Maybe you could use cURL to retrieve information. You can use cURL in the command-line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL